# Laravel CSRF protection with REST API

Tags: api, rest, laravel, csrf

I have this code at the top of my routes file

```
Route::when('*', 'csrf', array('post', 'put', 'delete'));
```

When I testing my RESTful API layer I get token mismatch error. How to solve this?

I use CSRF protection for regular form submissions a user might do. But how would that work for an API? I have my API calls grouped after my regular routes as below

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function () {
Route::resource('shows', 'ShowsApiController');
Route::resource('episode', 'EpisodesApiController');
Route::resource('genre', 'GenresApiController');
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

you will have such a class, add your routes to the $except

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
  protected $except = [
    'shows/*',
    'episode/*',
    'genre/*',
  ];
}
```

Comment: It's OK to add csrf exceptions, but this is not the right way to deal with API. Why this is not the right way to do API: cookies will be added to response - breaking stateless concept; laravel will try to start session - loosing some expensive time; You will have to do two times more testing when adding new middleware in web group; If You think about throttling, eventually You will need to migrate to API middleware group. Just my two cents.

Comment: to me, it seems like you have a better solution, yet sometimes people dosent care about the "stateless concept" or (INSERT A COMPLICATED BEST PRACTICE TERM HERE) , im not saying that they are bad or something but working with small apps dosent need to make things a bit more complicated

Comment: I agree with You about small apps, keeping them simple is crucial. But here comes another important part: if You are doing everything as simple as possible, then You are not improving Your skills. As a programmer I can say, that when I try to change something; do something differently, than always, I learn a lot. Cheers!

Comment: Added in 5.2 but still api response same error `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:`

Answer (score 9):

You should consider using different middleware groups for Your web and api layers. Laravel by default, depending on version You are using, uses `web` middleware group.

If You are not having line like this `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {` in Your `routes.php` file, then Your laravel version is that one which uses it by default. Check Your `RouteServiceProvider.php` file for this line: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L56.

If presented, remove `'middleware' => 'web'` part and group routes Yourself in `routes.php`. Then use `web` middleware for part where You need sessions, csrf and other stuff, and use `api` middleware where You don't need these things (`api` middleware group does not include sessions, encrypted cookies and csrf verifications).

Comment: Is there any possibility to disable in a specific controller

Comment: can you close/answer the question if you have found a solution

Comment: This answer should be selected!